# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, ratio

I need help determining what following series converges to using the ratio test.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
 It's the end that really has me confused with what to do with the factorial.

Comment: $\dfrac{(2(n+1))!}{(2n)!}=\dfrac{(2n+2)!}{(2n)!}=$$\dfrac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{ (2n)! }=(2n+2)(2n+1)$

Comment: $\dfrac{3^{2(n+1)}}{3^{2n}}=\dfrac{3^{2n+2}}{3^{2n}}=3^2=9$

Comment: The ratio test will not tell you to what value "this summation converges to" as you say in your question. It can only tell you whether it converges or not (if the limit of the ratio is different from 1).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1) Write down the series for $e^3$. Terms are better than the summation notation. Note that this converges (Ratio Test).

2) Write down the series for $e^{-3}$.

3) Look.

The Ratio Test also settles the convergence  of our series directly. Let $a_n=\dfrac{3^{2n}}{(2n)!}$. Then $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ simplifies to $\dfrac{9}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$.

Comment: He wrote explicitly that he needs to figure it out with the ratio test.